# Display video in Webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, video, webforms

I want to get a video url which is stored in a local db and display it in a webform. My problem is i have no idea of how to pass the url from code behind class to webform. I have displayed an image using labels by setting text property to image url but for videos it doesn't work.

Displayed the image like:

```
        string image;
        string video;
        Advertisement Ad= BusinessLogic.getAd(9);
        image = Ad.getImage();
        video = Ad.getVideo();

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('" + image + "');", true);
       lblImage.Text = "<img alt='' style=width:150px; height:150px src='" + image + "'/>";

       }
```

How  do i display a video by setting the url at runtime?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
lblVideo.Text = "<video width=320px height=240px src='" + video+ "'/>";
```

Comment: ...and that is just the beginning.